# Scala spark: Efficient check if condition is matched anywhere?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What I want is roughly equivalent to

```
df.where(<condition>).count() != 0
```

But I'm pretty sure it's not quite smart enough to stop once it finds any such violation. I would expect some sort of aggregator to be able to do this, but I haven't found one? I could do it with a `max` and some sort of conversion, but again I don't think it would necessarily know to quit (not being specific to bool, I'm not sure if understands no value is larger than true).

More specifically, I want to check if a column contains only a single element. Right now my best idea is to do this is by grabbing the first value and comparing everything.

Comment: do you want to check distinct value of any column is greater than one?

Comment: Yeah, but distinct() is one of the most expensive operations, so I don't actually want to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this option, it should be much faster:

```
df.where(<condition>).head(1).isEmpty
```

You can also try to define your conditions on a row together with scala's `exists` (which stops at the first occurence of `true`):

```
df.mapPartitions(rows => if(rows.exists(row => <condition>)) Iterator(1) else Iterator.empty).isEmpty
```

At the end you should benchmark the alternatives